# How can i use Django-mptt?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

I want to make a navigation through categories and subcategories in Django.

I install django-mptt and now i get this error."type object 'Category' has no attribute '_mptt_meta'  "

models.py

```
from mptt.models import MPTTModel, TreeForeignKey
# Create your models here.
class Category(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug=models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True, help_text='Uniue Value product page url, created from name.')
    is_active=models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    parent=TreeForeignKey('self',on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True, related_name='children')

    class MPTTMeta:
        order_insertion_by=['name']
```

thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make `Category` a subclass of `MPTTModel`:

```
from mptt.models import MPTTModel, TreeForeignKey

#                ↓ subclass of MPTTModel
class Category(MPTTModel):
    # …
```